# Identifying the I frames before and after a given time

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to find a method for finding the I Frame before and after an inputted time.  So far my method for finding the I frame preceding a time is

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type -v quiet input.mp4 | awk -F= '/pict_type=/ { if (index($2, "I")) { i=1; } else { i=0; } } /pkt_pts_time/ { if (i && ($2 <= 1)) print $2; }' | head -n 1
```

Yet this seems to identify the frame after the preceding I frame, not the I frame itself.  How do I get it to output the pkt_pts_time of the actual I frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be faster to do this with ffmpeg since it has an option to skip non-keyframes altogether.

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i video -an -vf showinfo -f null - 2>&1 | grep -oE "pts_time:[0-9\.]+"
```

Output e.g.

```
pts_time:0
pts_time:5
pts_time:10
pts_time:15
pts_time:20
pts_time:25
pts_time:30
```

grep is GNU grep. Values are in seconds.

Comment: Thanks!   That works!  Actually, I wonder, is there a way to get that value in frames?